# Calculating next destination by speed, distance and direction by degree angle

Tags: java, kotlin, libgdx

Calculating next 3d destination by speed, distance, and direction by degree angle. In the below code it does not give the correct destination value. Transform position and Movement destination is in Vector 3.

```
val distance = 1f // 1 metere
val speed = getEntitySpeed(entity, deltaTime) // 0.44
val newDistance = transform.rotation.dir() * speed 
val newDest = transform.position.cpy().sub(newDistance.x, 0f, newDistance.y).nor()

movement.destination.set(newDest.add(distance, 0f, distance))
```

Calculate the direction

```
inline fun Float.dir( ) : Vector2 {
    val direction = Vector2(1f, 0f)
    //Put here your default direction with length 1. This usually is a vector. pointing right.
    direction.rotate(this)
    if (abs(direction.x) > 0.707) { //a perfect diagonal in unit circle
        direction.x = sign(direction.x);
    } else {
        direction.x = 0f
    }
    if (abs(direction.y) > 0.707) {
        direction.y = sign(direction.y);
    } else {
        direction.y = 0f
    }
    return direction
}
```

The destination will use to calculate the velocity to add to position.

```
val distance = vec2()
distance.x = movement.destination.x - transform.position.x
distance.y = movement.destination.z - transform.position.z

val length = distance.len()

// Normalize
movement.velocity.x = distance.x / length * speed
movement.velocity.z = distance.y / length * speed


if (abs(movement.velocity.x) > abs(distance.x)) {
    movement.velocity.x = distance.x
}

if (abs(movement.velocity.z) > abs(distance.y)) {
    movement.velocity.z = distance.y
}
```

Calculate to move from position to given destination

```
transform.position.x += movement.velocity.x
transform.position.z += movement.velocity.z
```